# Allure_behave does not work: AllureFormatter is unknown

Tags: allure, python-behave

I have written some test cases in Python behave, and I want to use allure to run and generate reports. I have already installed `allure_behave`, but when I run the command in my feature file directory

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o result
```

it does not work, and the error is:

> `behave: error: format=allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter is unknown.`

Who knows why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like python wich run behave haven't installed allure_behave. Can you show output for this: "$ python -v  -m behave 2>&1  | grep 'allure_behave'" ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue along with upgrade pip warning.
I upgraded my pip from version 10 to 19

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then I installed allure-behave

```
pip install allure-behave
```

Then I executed below line

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o %allure_result_folder% ./features
```

I am not getting any error now.